# Detect certain second on html5 video with jquery

Tags: jquery, html5-video

How do I detect and execute something once a certain second in html5 video is reached with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found solution.

```
if($('yourTag')[0].currentTime == /*seconds*/){/*do something*/}
```

Comment: Have in mind that you may not get the *exact* same time every time. I would suggest adding a tolerance range, i.e. if($('yourTag')[0].currentTime >= time && $('yourTag')[0].currentTime < time + tolerance) ... Or use expire approach, anything after this time, but before next time.